# Creating a 3D mesh from elevation data?

Tags: 3d, gis, gdal

I'm looking to render some images from terrain elevation data, and was wondering what the best  tools are for this kind of thing.  Basically I would like to generate images of a mountain from different locations and perspectives.  The images can be somewhat crude and simple..

I've used the GDAL command line tools quite a bit, and gdaldem does a great job of creating top-down shaded relief maps, but I haven't found anything that does different camera orientations.

The two general approaches I am considering are:

- Use the GDAL python bindings and the equations for a pinhole camera and roll my own solution.  I'd like to avoid doing this if possible :)
- Use existing tools to either render the image, or at least generate a 3d mesh so I can render it another way

Comment: You can use [Blender's](http://blender.org/) Python bindings to generate and render a model.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly use the Delaunay triangulation routines in Numpy/Scipy to get the mesh you seek; but that is still just the first step down the long path of rolling your own complete solution.

For that matter, consider just using the digital terrain data and dividing every quad of four adjacent points in to two triangles by any ad-hoc scheme.  Isn't that a "3-D mesh"?  In other words, to create a triangular mesh (for additional 3D rendering):

- consider every point on the terrain raster to be joined to its four neighbors (N, S, E, W);
- additionally, split each quad with one more diagonal neighbor pair.  (For example: "categorically use the SW-NE diagonal", or "use the diagonal whose mean is closer to the mean of all four points in the quad".)

Matplotlib has some ability to render a mesh like this, but the amount of points you'll probably want for a reasonable patch of terrain is likely to almost totally swamp matplotlib's dynamic features (pan and zoom; even rotation for 3D).

Comment: HI,
can you check this where i am doing wrong
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062242/numpy-and-matplotlib-tri-triangulation-to-geotiff-in-python
or provide link of minimal example.

Answer (score -1):

I think [GrassGIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) might be able to do what you want to do.

You can go [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/3D/) for some screenshots of what GrassGIS can do.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: I think a downvote for a "correct answer with a link" is excessive. Even the link cited about "Link-dominated answers" accepts the answer "as long at is not ONLY a BARE link, they are OK".

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look at the [Virtual Terrain Project](http://vterrain.org/) before rolling your own. The goal of that project is *to foster the creation of tools for easily constructing any part of the real world in interactive, 3D digital form. .. The tools and their source code are freely shared to help accelerate the adoption and development of the necessary technologies.*

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: @DanH - Your psychic abilities are broken - I didn't downvote. Answers to old questions show up in tools available to all users with >10K rep - I'm not the only one of those. Votes are anonymous. I offered a suggestion to improve and possibly prolong the value of the answer, and yours. Not anonymous, and I'll stand behind it. You're welcome. And I won't lighten up doing that, btw.

Comment: @Mogsdad: I apologize about assuming you downvoted; both your comment and the downvote showed up at about the same time. My bad.  
FWIW, the text of this answer includes the words "Virtual Terrain Project", and the text of mine includes "Grass GIS".  So even if the links get stale, future users will be have a chance of finding the suggested sofwtware.

Comment: Maybe with the edits this addresses the OP's "what the best tools are for this kind of thing" and second approach: "Use existing tools to either render the image, or at least generate a 3d mesh so I can render it another way."